# So my Jinga code is not outputing an option

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

This is a cs50 pset if you didn't know.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Log In
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="custom-select" style="width: auto;" name="select">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Symbol</option>
                {% for stock in symbols %}
                    <option value={{ stock }}>{{ stock }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="shares" placeholder="Shares" type="text">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sell</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**Here is the app.py**

```
@app.route("/sell", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def sell():

    user = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE users.id=?", session['user_id'])[0]['username']

    if request.method == "GET":
        symbols = []
        unfiltered_stocks = db.execute("SELECT symbol FROM purchases WHERE user=?", user)

        for stock in unfiltered_stocks:
            symbols.append(stock['symbol'])

        return render_template("sell.html")
```

*You can consider that stocks is an array and its not empty*

**The Output is just the first placeholder option and nothing more**

Comment: Can you share the part of your Python code where you render this template? That would help greatly.

Comment: i have added part of the app.py file. what more do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `render_template()`, you can pass Python variables to it which makes them available in your Jinja template.

Change `return render_template("sell.html")` to `return render_template("sell.html", symbols=symbols)`

Comment: Yes but there is a for loop going on in the jinga and I don't think you can pass a variable from the app.py and iterate over it in the for loop. If its possible explain how?

Comment: You can pass variable from Python code to your Jinja template using render_template and iterate over it in for loop (for/endfor), just like in your existing code.